# Would pull be better than push from a set top box?

Tags: rest, architecture

We work in the area of video streaming and we are writing some software for a set top box that queries our server for a list of channels (NBC,FOX etc) so that it can select one. Also it needs to tell the server what it is currently doing (i.e. which channel selected, is it playing or paused etc) as the user can control the STB with remote control.

Also from another UI to the server another user can change the channel that is played on the STB.

So my question is an architecture one - would it be better for the STB to poll the server every so often (say few seconds) or should the server push the changes and check the STB every few seconds. There could be 100s of set to boxes.

I was thinking about exposing a number of web services and then the STB would poll and with each poll if there is change from another user it can then react otherwise each poll would be a status update.

In addition, whatever design we come up with we should be able to expose our API to 3rd party STB manufacturers so that they work with us.

Comment: Hi JD. It is an interesting problem. How critical is it to have the information from each STB in real time on the servers? What is the maximum delay you can tolerate?

Comment: You never provided feedback, do you mind sharing how did you solve your problem?